# Image not appearing... JS (p5.js)

Tags: javascript, html, processing, p5.js

This is coded in a javascript library called p5.js see: https://p5js.org/reference/

So I set up a basic code to try and get a custom cursor...

```
var img;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1000, 650);
  img = loadImage("assets/arrowmouse.png");
  image(img, mouseX, mouseY);
}

function draw() {
  background(20, 155, 255);
  fill(0, 0, 0);
}
```

No image appears so I'm getting a blue screen (my background)

Comment: Note this is copy-paste syntax exactly as done in the documentation

Comment: Why not use `css` to set the custom cursor? For example [**CodePen Demo**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/deNQeY)

Comment: well js fiddle isnt even running it although the library is available but here look at this on the reference page

Comment: https://p5js.org/examples/image-load-and-display-image.html

Comment: You haven't called any of these functions in your code. So do setup();draw(); Does it change anything??

Comment: No it doesn't because it is default called in the library the draw function repeats until otherwise told to stop.

Comment: well about that cs thing.. its not just the cursor. I need to be able to call multiple images for a game im making. in fact i need these images a lot

Comment: I see in the references that loadImage gets an optional callback, so what would happen if you do `loadImage("assets/arrowmouse.png",image(img, mouseX, mouseY))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**

Its a google chrome security block. I used firefox and it worked fine.

---

Solved in a YouTube comment: [**7.8: Objects and Images - p5.js Tutorial**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVYGyaxG4To)

had to tweak syntax too it looks like this now:

```
var img; function preload(){ 
arrowMouse = loadImage("assets/arrowmouse.png"); 
} 
function setup(){ 
createCanvas(1000,650); 
} 
function draw(){ 
background(20,155,255); 
fill(0,0,0); cursor("none"); 
image(arrowMouse, mouseX, mouseY,20,30); 
}
```

but that wont work in chrome.

This also may help: [**Disable same origin policy in Chrome**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)

Thanks to all that tried to help!

Comment: Could you explain more about this Chrome security block? This might help others in future who are experiencing the same or similar problem.

Comment: solved in a youtube comment of a comment

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVYGyaxG4To

look for the comment from 
Márk Molnár

Comment: had to tweak syntax too it looks like this now:

var img;
function preload(){
  arrowMouse = loadImage("assets/arrowmouse.png");

}
function setup() {
    createCanvas(1000,650);


}

function draw() {

    background(20,155,255);
    fill(0,0,0);
    cursor("none");
    image(arrowMouse, mouseX, mouseY,20,30);

}

but that wont work in chrome

Comment: this also may help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome

Comment: If this is the answer to the question, please mark it as accepted so your answer stop showing up as needing an answer.

Comment: Seems like firefox is also blocking this.